# HighCharts annotation to a PIE

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to put a label on top of a pie series, which is the summ of the bar series like the next screen (**Global BU(s) Overview**).

I am using the label tag, but since it's displayed on the right side of the graph, the absolute positionning of the label and of the pie places them on left on full screen (see second image), which is not what we want.

I can use position percentage like [90%, 20%] for the pie but not the label. Is there any way to **put the label on top of the pie** and make it "follow" it ? I saw the annotation docs but can't find exemples of this case.

Also I would love to **make the pie bigger in full screen**, is there any way to do it ?

Thanks in advance !

[image: Classic display, which is ok]

[image: Full Screen Display]

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Could you reproduce your chart in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/